# How do I stop the user from manually closing a VB6 automated instance of Word?

Tags: vb6, word-automation

My question is about absolute control over automated instances. I'm using VB6 to automate the generation of forms used in our workplace. The app is in Beta and I've written a User Manual to introduce the application to new users; explaining the sub-functions of the GUI. I use a command button on the GUI to open and close the User Manual in an instance of Word. All this is fine until the user closes the Word app manually while the app is running. This kills the Word instance, but I need to either stop the user from closing the Word instance, or have the app realize the instance is gone. My automation knowledge is pretty shallow. I adapt sub routines from VBA macros. Please help.

Comment: Set the ControlBox property to false (in form designer) (using VB6, not VBA).  There are still ways thay can close it, but you sort of have the illusion of control

Comment: Do the users need to see the forms that are being created or is your application filling in the data then saving the form?

Comment: Building on lardymonkey's comment, you could run the instance as minimized or possibly move the window off the visible portion of the screen, but the user could still interfere as long as there's an instance on the taskbar, so it's not the best solution.  @lardymonkey might be hinting at something else altogether, though - perhaps an instance of Word doesn't even have to open or display at all.

Comment: I use bookmarks in the User Manual (UM) to jump about in the document as the user moves the mouse over each control on the main app GUI. If the manual is up when the user is driving the GUI, the document jumps to the bookmarked section for the control the mouse hovering over. It works as intended unless the user closes the UM themselves. This causes problems when the GUI tries to close the Word instance; either when the user clicks the UM toggle, or the GUI is shutting down. Since the user closed the UM from the desktop, the app hangs when it tries to close the Word instance it opened.

Comment: I need to work on framing my problem descriptions more clearly. After reading the above responses, I realized how vague my post was. Sorry about that. – Doc937

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to either stop the user from closing the Word instance, or have
>   the app realize the instance is gone

You can do both - declare your Word variable using the "Give me events" syntax and it will raise the `DocumentBeforeClose` event in your code.

```
Public WithEvents mWordApp As Word.Application

Sub DoStuff()
    Set mWordApp = New Word.Application
    '// open doc ...
    mWordApp.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub mWordApp_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = MsgBox("Word is closing, keep open?", vbYesNo) = vbYes
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is solution I'm going to need. I have to work that in to the main GUI code to reign in the user. I'll try to cut it in today at work, and get back to you with the results.

Thank you, Alex!   Thank you all for your help.

Comment: This was the solution I needed. It allows me to trap any of my Office product instance events the user may inject directly into the desktop object. Thank you Alex.

Answer (score 0):

The "... WithEvents ..." declaration of the MSOffice Application instance is the solution to this problem. The event list for the app allows the programmer full automated control of the instance from behind the curtain. Thanks all!